# Why do new videos get posted in categories that are not "assignable"?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

According to the docs at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories, a `videoCategory` having `assignable` set to `false` means that videos cannot *"be associated with the category."* However, in reality, I frequently see newly-posted videos in non-assignable categories. For instance, category 44, *Trailers*, is not assignable:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoCategoryListResponse",
 "etag": "\"sZ5p5Mo8dPpfIzLYQBF8QIQJym0/eD61zd9m0XnQ2ZM5b9n0Q8fREKY\"",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#videoCategory",
   "etag": "\"sZ5p5Mo8dPpfIzLYQBF8QIQJym0/x5NxSf5fz8hn4loSN4rvhwzD_pY\"",
   "id": "44",
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
    "title": "Trailers",
    "assignable": false
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

But https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fV4CL3ec-C0, published under half an hour ago, is in that category, as can be seen by querying the `videos` `list` API:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"sZ5p5Mo8dPpfIzLYQBF8QIQJym0/NWLSF1NxIRL6hEGPkRpbFpl6ShA\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"sZ5p5Mo8dPpfIzLYQBF8QIQJym0/TMALCjmdQYcndOpePwtvPYbaBBI\"",
   "id": "fV4CL3ec-C0",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2016-11-07T11:00:03.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCxk91kWNnZEIyE-1HgqzvHw",
    "title": "USS Indianapolis: The Legacy - Trailer",
    "description": "Based on the largest collection of original source material available on the subject, The Legacy Project is a complete re-telling of the story of the USS Indianapolis, told first hand, by those who lived through the experience.",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fV4CL3ec-C0/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fV4CL3ec-C0/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fV4CL3ec-C0/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fV4CL3ec-C0/sddefault.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     },
     "maxres": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fV4CL3ec-C0/maxresdefault.jpg",
      "width": 1280,
      "height": 720
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "GravitasVODGlobal",
    "tags": [
     "Military",
     "WWII",
     "Indianapolis",
     "McVay",
     "Navy",
     "Atomic Bomb",
     "Sharks",
     "Cruiser",
     "Hunter Scott",
     "Pacific War"
    ],
    "categoryId": "44",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
    "localized": {
     "title": "USS Indianapolis: The Legacy - Trailer",
     "description": "Based on the largest collection of original source material available on the subject, The Legacy Project is a complete re-telling of the story of the USS Indianapolis, told first hand, by those who lived through the experience."
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

By what mechanism do new videos get added to non-`assignable` categories? Are there some secret APIs available only to certain clients that YouTube has special deals with, or is there a publicly-documented mechanism for adding videos to non-`assignable` categories? Either way, is there any way for developers to distinguish these categories that are only nominally non-`assignable` from those that will truly not accept new videos via any means?

Comment: So the newly uploaded video is not set manually with the trailer category? And it is automatically set with that. Try to reupload the video and check if it set again with video category trailer.

Comment: @KENdi I didn't upload the video, and don't have the original, so have no means to reupload it. I see no reason to think that the category was set automatically, although I can't disprove it.